# How to set GridViewBrowseColumn (Telerik radgridview in winforms) initial directory

Tags: winforms, telerik

I am using radgridview (telerik controls) in winforms application. One of columns is GridViewBrowseColumn. But I don't know how to set **initial directory** for this control. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

RadGridView offers the **CellEditorInitialized** event which is fired right after the editor is activated. [GridBrowseEditor](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/editors/default-editors) is the default editor for the [GridViewBrowseColumn](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/columns/column-types/gridviewbrowsecolumn). If you want to set any initially selected folder in the editor, it is necessary to set its **Value** to the desired path:

```
    public partial class RadForm1 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public RadForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridViewBrowseColumn browseColumn = new GridViewBrowseColumn();
         
        this.radGridView1.Columns.Add(browseColumn);
        this.radGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        this.radGridView1.CellEditorInitialized+=radGridView1_CellEditorInitialized;
    }

    private void radGridView1_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        GridBrowseEditor browseEditor = e.ActiveEditor as GridBrowseEditor;
        RadBrowseEditorElement el = browseEditor.EditorElement as RadBrowseEditorElement;
        el.DialogType = BrowseEditorDialogType.FolderBrowseDialog;
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = el.BrowseDialog as FolderBrowserDialog;
        if (el.Value==null)
        {
            el.Value =  @"C:\Projects";
        }  
    }
}
```

I hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dess. Your answer was helpful. I just edited two lines of your code. I want to have a **open file dialog** but your was **folder browse dialog**. I write it here maybe helpful for others:

```
private void gv_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, 
   GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    GridBrowseEditor browseEditor = e.ActiveEditor as GridBrowseEditor;
        RadBrowseEditorElement el = browseEditor.EditorElement as 
        RadBrowseEditorElement;

        el.DialogType = BrowseEditorDialogType.OpenFileDialog;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = el.Dialog as OpenFileDialog;
        ofd.InitialDirectory = @"D:\";

}
```